# How to prevent API data exposure if some of the endpoints can't be authorized?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, security

Sorry maybe this question was asked already but I can't find anything that will answer my questions.

I have two apps and api:

1. Checkout - React app which is frontend for any user in the internet.
2. Admin - closed app for admins only closed under Bearer tokens.
3. API - node js app which is connected to db.

Almost all API endpoints are closed under auth for admins only. All endpoints have strict CORS policy to only allowed origins.

But some API endpoints are open to public. All of this "open" endpoints are GET endpoints. I need them to get info for 1st React app (checkout).

So theoretically bad actor can only read some of the data from them which is not sensitive and has  no way to alter or delete data or access any other data under auth endpoints.

**Question: is there a way to protect those "open" endpoints?**

I closed all possible endpoints under Bearer tokens authorization. I added stric CORS policy for all api endpoints.

Comment: `Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP)` Have you ever tried this? https://lab.wallarm.com/owasp-top-10-2021-proposal-based-on-a-statistical-data/

Comment: Hope few things might reduce attack intensity, like rate limiting, checking client types, and  using post method so that people dont use browser to check the info, black listing ip, and may be api call rates to calls from clients which post a valid jwt token

Comment: What do you mean by "protect"? You can do rate-limiting or something like that. But in the end of the day, if the endpoint has to be callable by the public, it is callable by the public ...

Comment: Furthermore CORS is not a server-side security measue, but a client side. So serving or denying requests based on the Origin header might be a bad idea. This can easily be forged ...

Comment: @derpirscher I meant how to hide as much as possible info from outside world.

Comment: Well, don't expose info you don't want to be exposed. And I don't know whether your API is openly documented, but you may decide to exclude certain endpoints from the docs. But I wouldn't call that "protection"